# Align sides of a cube to a curve of a circular array with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'd like to align the sides of the cubes placed on the circle to the curve so that the gaps are eliminated. This must be adjusted according to the radius so I can't just put in static numbers.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to keep the result as instances or can it be a mesh?

Comment: can be a mesh too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to do that is to reproduce in geometry nodes what array and curve modifiers already do. There can be a more simple solution but reproducing these modifiers allows a more generic usage of these principles.

- Array the quadilateral the same amount of time the curve circle has segments
- Project this array along the curve circle

[image]

The array node tree mimic the array modifier (except for the object offset):

This is done by creating a mesh line with the wanted amount of point and instancing the input shape along its points.

[image]

Now the part that make the arrayed shape follow the curve:

It uses the curve factor relatively to the array X axis, by mapping the array X coordinates (between min/max of the array boundings) to 0, 1 (the curve factor).

Then we can calculate Y and Z parts with Y to be along the curve normal and Z along its binormal, and add all that to determinate the final shape points.

[image]

Using it:

[image]

[image] (made with 4.0.2)

Comment: wow thank you so much! I thought this should actually be an easy task but damn is it complex, thanks for solving and explaining the solution!

Answer (score 3):

I just figured another way myself, don't know why I didn't have this in mind before..
I just use a circle with lesser vertices  and extrude it. That's basically it. Then I split at edges.

[image]

Comment: Smart approach!